# How do I load the json from mulitple rows in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter

I am trying to load data fetched from a web service, but nothing is coming through. The JSON is coming back ok, but i can't get it decoded for use in my app. I can also use the url in a web browser and the JSON comes back fine. I think I may be trying to decode and load the JSON wrong.
Any help with where I'm going wrong would be great. Thanks everyone.

Cheers,

Paul

JSON sample:

```
{
   "rows":[
      {
         "JOBID":23,
         "START_DATE":1588809600000,
         "START_TIME":"07:30",
         "JOB_NAME":"Cleaner"
      },
      {
         "JOBID":23,
         "START_DATE":1588809600000,
         "START_TIME":"08:30",
         "JOB_NAME":"Manager"
      }
   ]
}
```

Model:

```
class StaffJobs {
  List<SJRows> sjRows;

  StaffJobs({this.sjRows});

  StaffJobs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['rows'] != null) {
      sjRows = List<SJRows>();
      json['rows'].forEach((v) {
        sjRows.add(SJRows.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.sjRows != null) {
      data['rows'] = this.sjRows.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class SJRows {
  int jobId;
  int startDate;
  String startTime;
  String jobName;

  SJRows(
      {this.jobId,
      this.startDate,
      this.startTime,
      this.jobName});

  SJRows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    jobId = json['JOBID'];
    startDate = json['START_DATE'];
    startTime = json['START_TIME'];
    jobName = json['JOB_NAME'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['JOBID'] = this.jobId;
    data['START_DATE'] = this.startDate;
    data['START_TIME'] = this.startTime;
    data['JOB_NAME'] = this.jobName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

In the initState where I print the job count, I get 0.

Also near the end of the code where I am displaying a couple of fields in a ListTile, I'm not sure how to reference the data.

Just after where I test for a response.statusCode of 200, I have tried printing the response.body to the console and all the JSON is there, so the http.get is working correctly.

I also see an error in the console:
**E/flutter (15432): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast**

in the screen where I am trying to load the staff jobs I have the following code:

```
class MyJobs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyJobsState createState() => new _MyJobsState();
}

class _MyJobsState extends State<MyJobs> {
  List<StaffJobs> jobs = List();
  bool isLoading = false;

  _getJobs() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    final response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull('$jobUrl'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      jobs = (json.decode(response.body) as List).map((data) => StaffJobs.fromJson(data)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load jobs');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getJobs();
    print('Count = ${jobs.length}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: rmoAppBar(subText: 'My Jobs'),
      drawer: RmoMenu(),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: jobs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(jobs[index].sjRows.jobName),    <------ Not sure how to reference data
                    subtitle: Text(jobs[index].sjRows.startTime),  <--- This doesn't compile
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just not 
decoding correctly.

Following code while help you more.

```
class MyJobs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyJobsState createState() => new _MyJobsState();
}

class _MyJobsState extends State<MyJobs> {
  StaffJobs jobs;
  bool isLoading = false;

  _getJobs() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    final response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull('$jobUrl'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      jobs = StaffJobs.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load jobs');
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getJobs();
    print('Count = ${jobs.sjRows.length}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: rmoAppBar(subText: 'My Jobs'),
      drawer: RmoMenu(),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: jobs.sjRows.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(jobs.sjRows[index].jobName),
                    subtitle: Text(jobs.sjRows[index].startTime),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}

class StaffJobs {
  List<SJRows> sjRows;

  StaffJobs({this.sjRows});

  StaffJobs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['rows'] != null) {
      sjRows = List<SJRows>();
      json['rows'].forEach((v) {
        sjRows.add(SJRows.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.sjRows != null) {
      data['rows'] = this.sjRows.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class SJRows {
  int jobId;
  int startDate;
  String startTime;
  String jobName;

  SJRows({this.jobId, this.startDate, this.startTime, this.jobName});

  SJRows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    jobId = json['JOBID'];
    startDate = json['START_DATE'];
    startTime = json['START_TIME'];
    jobName = json['JOB_NAME'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['JOBID'] = this.jobId;
    data['START_DATE'] = this.startDate;
    data['START_TIME'] = this.startTime;
    data['JOB_NAME'] = this.jobName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Viren, thanks for the answer. Really appreciate it. I have one problem though, the code won't compile. I get an error on the :

jobs = StaffJobs.fromJson(response);

error: The argument type 'Response' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [rostermeon] lib\pages\my_shifts.dart:31)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: @PaulCoshott check now. if this doesn't work then i need jobUrl to help you more.

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked great. Really appreciate the help. Have a great day.